# Is there a way to combine multiple traits in order to define a new trait?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to combine multiple traits (by inheritance?) in order to define a new trait? I'm looking for something like concepts in C++:

```cpp
auto concept newConcept<typename T> : concept1<T>, concept2<T>, concept3<T> {};
```

Suppose I want to make a new trait that inherits from `Clone`, `Default` and some other traits, is that possible?

Comment: I was searching for a question like this under the term "super traits" so I just comment it here and hopefully someone may find it with this term later.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Yep!

```rust
trait NewTrait: Clone + Default + OtherTraits {}
impl<T> NewTrait for T where T: Clone + Default + OtherTraits {}
```

Comment: Thanks (tried this with commas... but it didn't work).  I searched for this for a long time, too bad it is not in the guide.

Comment: It is mentioned in the reference, though: http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#traits Yeah, I tripped up on this as well :)

Comment: You can write a macro trait_alias as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291584/macro-for-defining-trait-aliases

Comment: This is called a blanket implementation https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-are-blanket-implementations/49904