# Do macros not expand interpolated token trees?

Tags: rust

Why does [this](http://is.gd/F5GGsk):

```
macro_rules! a_macro {
    ($($a:tt)+) => ($($a)+);
}   

fn main() {
    let x:u32 = 1;
    let y:u32 = a_macro!(-x);
}
```

fail to compile with

```
<anon>:2:23: 2:25 error: unexpected token: `an interpolated tt`
<anon>:2     ($($a:tt)+) => ($($a)+);
                               ^~
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The why is: it's not implemented yet. This is a known limitation (as of Rust 1.0). `tt` arguments to macros [are useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30293051), but they must always be forwarded to macros when used.

Comment: This saddens me. I was hoping to make combinators with macros, and being unable to return tokens makes that painful. :-(

Comment: @user: macros are very much a work in progress at the moment; already incredibly useful, but nowhere near as flexible as they could be.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Not complaining about their limitations so much as wishing I could re-order chronology to use the spectacular Rust of the future. :-D

Comment: Rest assured macros are already [insane (nightly branch)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7667b480a0835bd8740a&version=nightly)