# Repetitive trait bounds on generic structs

Tags: rust, traits

I am doing some USB work and my design has a generic buffer type with trait bounds `AsRef<[u8]>` and `AsMut<[u8]>`.  I am finding that these trait bounds "infect" all higher layers and I have to repeatedly specify them.  Is there a way to tidy this up?  Example:

```
pub struct Transfer<B: AsRef<[u8]> + AsMut<[u8]>> {
    pub buf: B,
    // ...
}

impl<B: AsRef<[u8]> + AsMut<[u8]>> Transfer<B> {
    // ...
}

pub struct Device<B: AsRef<[u8]> + AsMut<[u8]>> {
    transfers: Vec<Option<Transfer<B>>>,
    // ...
}

impl<B: AsRef<[u8]> + AsMut<[u8]>> Device<B> {
    // ...
}

impl<B: AsRef<[u8]> + AsMut<[u8]>> Evented for Device<B> {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/26983355/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/26070559/155423. Use `trait Buffer: AsRef<[u8]> + AsMut<[u8]> {}
impl<T> Buffer for T where T: AsRef<[u8]> + AsMut<[u8]> {}`.

Comment: The answer to that question definitely applies to my question (thanks!), but I feel there may be additional answers to my question.  For example, traits have a means to tuck away additional types and bounds (associated types); is there some similar mechanism for generic structs?

Comment: I'm also stuck with this. I wrote about an idea here https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/rfc-idea-associated-type-parameters/3361