# Rust Trait object conversion

Tags: rust, type-conversion, traits, coercion

The following code won't compile due to two instances of this error:

> error[E0277]: the trait bound `Self: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied

I don't understand why `Sized` is required in this instance as both `&self` and `&Any` are pointers and the operation does not require knowledge of the size of the structure that implements the trait, it only requires knowledge of the pointer itself and the type it is converting from and to, which it will have because `&self` is generic when implemented inside a trait.

I think this may be an instance of the compiler enforcing unnecessary constraints and I've considered filing an issue with the rust-lang GitHub repo but I figured I should probably see if someone here knows something I don't before I go file an issue.

```
use std::any::Any;

trait Component: Any {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &Any {
        self
    }

    fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Any {
        self
    }
}
```

The alternative to this is to make `as_any()` and `as_any_mut()` required functions for the structs that implement this trait, but for those structures the implementation would always be exactly as displayed here down to each individual character, resulting in several instances of identical boilerplate code.

Comment: I removed my answer because I can't find the documentation link quick enough. It is my understanding though, that `Self` in traits is unsized and without explicitly marking your trait as `Sized` the compiler will see it as unsized and error.

Comment: I think making the methods required is the way to go. At least I've seen that pattern before. To avoid the duplicate code, you could write a simple macro `impl_conversion_functions!()` or something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found what I consider to be a great solution that didn't require new compiler features.

```
pub trait Component {
    // ...
}

pub trait ComponentAny: Component + Any {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &Any;
    fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Any;
}

impl<T> ComponentAny for T
    where T: Component + Any
{
    fn as_any(&self) -> &Any {
        self
    }

    fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Any {
        self
    }
}
```

From here, I just change all my APIs to accept `ComponentAny` instead of `Component`.  Because `Any` is automatically implemented for any `'static` type, `ComponentAny` is now automatically implemented for any `'static` type that implements `Component`.  Thanks to [Is there a way to combine multiple traits in order to define a new trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983355/is-there-a-way-to-combine-multiple-traits-in-order-to-define-a-new-trait) for the idea.

Answer (score 9):

Dynamically sized types can also implement traits. In particular, when you define an object-safe trait, the compiler also defines a dynamically sized type with the same name as the trait, which lets you use object types such as `&Component`.

Object types such as `&Component` or `&Any` are not just ordinary pointers; they're **fat pointers**. A fat pointer combines a pointer to the data and another piece of data: for object types, it's a pointer to the vtable; for slices, it's the length of the slice.

When casting from a regular pointer (e.g. a `&Button`) to an object type, the compiler statically knows which vtable to put in the fat pointer (e.g. `Button`'s vtable for `Any`). On the other hand, Rust doesn't support casting from an object type to another object type (e.g. from `&Component` to `&Any`), because there's not enough data in an object to initialize the new fat pointer. This is why the compiler adds this note to the error message:

```
= note: required for the cast to the object type `std::any::Any + 'static`
```

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Require that all types implementing `Component` be `Sized`:

   ```
   trait Component: Any + Sized {
       fn as_any(&self) -> &Any {
           self
       }

       fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Any {
           self
       }
   }
   ```

   This has the consequence that you will not be able to use object types such as `&Component` or `Box<Component>` at all.
2. Make the `as_any` and `as_any_mut` methods only available when `Self` is `Sized`:

   ```
   trait Component: Any {
       fn as_any(&self) -> &Any
           where Self: Sized
       {
           self
       }

       fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Any
           where Self: Sized
       {
           self
       }
   }
   ```

   This way, you can still use object types for the trait, but you will not be able to call `as_any` and `as_any_mut` on them.

Comment: That makes sense.  Unfortunately for my particular situation I do need to be able to call these functions on trait objects.  I'll see if I can find another way