# Provided method casting &self to trait object

Tags: rust, traits

I have a trait in which I want to provide a method. The method is to be implemented in terms of some helpers that have no business being inside the trait and are non-trivial enough that dynamic polymorphism makes more sense than making them generic. So I have code along the lines of

```
fn use_trait(x: &Trait) {
    println!("object says {}", x.needed());
}

trait Trait {
    fn needed(&self) -> &str;

    fn provided(&self) {
        use_trait(self);
    }
}

struct Struct();

impl Trait for Struct {
    fn needed(&self) -> &str {
        "Hello, world!"
    }
}

fn main() {
    Struct().provided();
}
```

Which, however, [does not compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=647f6e1a104daf70a961a4f82e347b7c&version=stable&backtrace=0), with error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Self: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
 --> <anon>:9:19
  |
9 |         use_trait(self);
  |                   ^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `Self`
  |
  = help: consider adding a `where Self: std::marker::Sized` bound
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `Trait`
```

I understand why—it is not guaranteed somebody won't implement the trait for an unsized type (converting from `&T where T: Trait` to `&Trait` requires `T: Sized`, but the declaration does not require that).

However, the advice will not do what I need. I can add

```
fn needed(&self) -> &str where Self: Sized
```

but then the `needed()` method *won't* be accessible on `&Trait` (because `Trait : ?Sized`), which renders the thing useless, because the type (the actual one that does something useful) is *always* handled as `Arc<Trait>`. And adding

```
trait Trait: Sized
```

is even worse, because that does not permit `&Trait` at all (`Trait` as a type is unsized, so `Trait` type does *not* implement trait `Trait`).

Of course I can simply make

```
fn use_trait<T: Trait>(x: &T)
```

but there is a lot behind it in the real code, so I don't want monomorphisation there especially since the trait is otherwise always handled as trait object.

Is there any way to tell Rust that all types that `impl Trait` must be sized and here is a definition of a method that should work for all of them?

Comment: See also [Rust Trait object conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41604107/155423)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enhanced version of [@JoshuaEntrekin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42123422/201725):

The helper `as_trait` function can be put in an auxiliary trait that gets blanket implementation for all `Sized` types trying to implement `Trait`. Then the implementer of `Trait` does not have to do anything special and the conversion works.

```
fn use_trait(x: &Trait) {
    println!("object says {}", x.needed());
}

trait Trait : AsTrait {
    fn needed(&self) -> &str;

    fn provided(&self) where Self : AsTrait {
        use_trait(self.as_trait());
    }
}

trait AsTrait {
    fn as_trait(&self) -> &Trait;
}

impl<T : Trait + Sized> AsTrait for T {
    fn as_trait(&self) -> &Trait { self }
}

struct Struct();

impl Trait for Struct {
    fn needed(&self) -> &str {
        "Hello, world!"
    }
}

fn main() {
    Struct().provided();
}
```

(on [play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d80593f060c05f1de5a7fa3ccf271c19&version=stable&backtrace=0)).

<s>It would also be possible to simply put `provided` in the auxiliary trait, but then it would have to dynamically dispatch to the other methods of `Self` unnecessarily.</s>

---

Update: Actually, the point is that it should still be possible to override `provided`.

Now the above can be improved further by making it generic. There is [std::makrer::Unsize](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html), which is unstable at the time of this writing. We can't make

```
trait Trait : Unsize<Trait>
```

because Rust does not allow [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), but fortunately it is enough to put the constraint on the method. So

```
fn use_trait(x: &Trait) {
    println!("object says {}", x.needed());
}

trait Trait {
    fn needed(&self) -> &str;

    fn provided(&self) where Self: AsObj<Trait> {
        use_trait(self.as_obj());
    }
}

trait AsObj<Tr: ?Sized> {
    fn as_obj(&self) -> &Trait;
}

// For &'a Type for Sized Type
impl<Type: Trait> AsObj<Trait> for Type {
    fn as_obj(&self) -> &Trait { self }
}

// For trait objects
impl AsObj<Trait> for Trait {
    fn as_obj(&self) -> &Trait { self }
}

struct Struct();

impl Trait for Struct {
    fn needed(&self) -> &str {
        "Hello, world!"
    }
    
    fn provided(&self) {
        println!("Aber dieses Objekt sagt Grüß Gott, Welt!"); // pardon my German, it is rusty.
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s: &Trait = &Struct();
    s.provided();
}
```

(on [play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20use_trait(x%3A%20%26Trait)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22object%20says%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20x.needed())%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atrait%20Trait%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20needed(%26self)%20-%3E%20%26str%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20provided(%26self)%20where%20Self%3A%20AsObj%3CTrait%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20use_trait(self.as_obj())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Atrait%20AsObj%3CTr%3A%20%3FSized%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20as_obj(%26self)%20-%3E%20%26Trait%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20For%20%26%27a%20Type%20for%20Sized%20Type%0Aimpl%3CType%3A%20Trait%3E%20AsObj%3CTrait%3E%20for%20Type%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20as_obj(%26self)%20-%3E%20%26Trait%20%7B%20self%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20For%20trait%20objects%0Aimpl%20AsObj%3CTrait%3E%20for%20Trait%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20as_obj(%26self)%20-%3E%20%26Trait%20%7B%20self%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Struct()%3B%0A%0Aimpl%20Trait%20for%20Struct%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20needed(%26self)%20-%3E%20%26str%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Hello%2C%20world!%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20provided(%26self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Aber%20dieses%20Objekt%20sagt%20Gr%C3%BC%C3%9F%20Gott%2C%20Welt!%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20pardon%20my%20German%2C%20it%20is%20rusty.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20s%3A%20%26Trait%20%3D%20%26Struct()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20s.provided()%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0))

This finally makes it transparent for the implementors of other versions.

See also [this users thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/specifying-that-trait-should-be-object-safe-for-purpose-of-casting-to-object/11564/).

Answer (score 2):

You need an additional `as_trait` function on `Trait` and its implementations:

```
trait Trait {
    fn needed(&self) -> &str;

    fn provided(&self) {
        use_trait(self.as_trait());
    }

    fn as_trait(&self) -> &Trait;
}

struct Struct();

impl Trait for Struct {
    fn needed(&self) -> &str {
        "Hello, world!"
    }

    fn as_trait(&self) -> &Trait {
        self as &Trait
    }
}
```

You can try it on the playground. ([trait objects](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e5aa203cac8f221c2f9afe10a7c9606e&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Comment: "an unsized type " trait objects have a size; two `usizes`. A bare trait by itself, without an object, is an unsized type.

Comment: Can you explain why the `as_trait()` method is needed, and `use_trait(self as &Trait)` doesn't work directly in `provided()`?

Comment: @ChrisEmerson, I'll add the explanation to the question itself. It is pretty obvious why it does not work the simple way.