# How do we convert a Rust string to a gtk::type::String?

Tags: rust, gtk-rs

I'm trying to create a `ComboBox`, especially the model for it:

```
let type_in_col = &[gtk::Type::String];
let list_model = ListStore::new(type_in_col);
list_model.insert_with_values(None, &[0], &[""]);
list_model.insert_with_values(None, &[0], &["h"]);
list_model.insert_with_values(None, &[0], &["H"]);
list_model.insert_with_values(None, &[0], &["W"]);
list_model.insert_with_values(None, &[0], &["S"]);
```

This piece of code gave me this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
--> src\widgets\daywidget.rs:36:1
   |
36 | #[widget]
   | ^^^^^^^^^ `str` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   |
= help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `str`
= note: required for the cast to the object type `gtk::ToValue`
```

(the error is not very precise because I'm using Relm)

Comment: Just a guess, but you might want `String` instead of `str`. You can convert `str` to `String` with `"example".to_string()`.

Comment: I managed to find an example which is doing `list_model.insert_with_values(None, &[0], &[&("S".to_value()) as &ToValue]);`

Comment: You should add that as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the following, instead:

```
let type_in_col = &[gtk::Type::String];
let list_model = ListStore::new(type_in_col);
list_model.insert_with_values(None, &[0], &[&""]);
list_model.insert_with_values(None, &[0], &[&"h"]);
list_model.insert_with_values(None, &[0], &[&"H"]);
list_model.insert_with_values(None, &[0], &[&"W"]);
list_model.insert_with_values(None, &[0], &[&"S"]);
```

since `SetValue` is implemented for `&T where T: ?Sized`.

You cannot cast from `&str` to `&ToValue`: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604107/rust-trait-object-conversion) for the reasons.

Comment: `this function takes 4 parameters but 3 parameters were supplied (expected 4 parameters) [E0061] [4 times]` at the `None`s

Comment: @Zelphir: You're probably using a `TreeStore` instead of a `ListStore`. The former also needs a parent to be specified, which can be `None`.