# Specify relation between types as a trait or macro

Tags: rust, traits

I would like to make something like the following work:

```
use std::ops::Add;

trait CanBeAdded: Sized where f64: Add<Self> {}

fn add2<X: CanBeAdded>(x: X) {}

fn main() {}
```

The above fails to compile:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `f64: std::ops::Add<X>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:5:1
  |
5 | fn add2<X: CanBeAdded>(x: X) {}
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::ops::Add<X>` is not implemented for `f64`
  |
  = help: consider adding a `where f64: std::ops::Add<X>` bound
  = note: required by `CanBeAdded`
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e6d54a18057ec349204bf8cd7745e089&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

I'm trying to assert the existence of certain `impl`s via a trait: i.e. `X: CanBeAdded` implies `f64: Add<X>`. While I can add the bounds to the where clause of the function like this:

```
fn add2<X>(x: X) where f64: Add<X> { }
```

I have many of them so it gets unwieldy and I would prefer to not repeat the bounds over and over. Is there a good solution to this? For example, is it possible to include a macro that expands to a series of `where` clauses?

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there a way to combine multiple traits in order to define a new trait](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26983355/155423)?

Comment: Hmm, it's different because it involves a second type, `f64` -- it involves the relationship between two or more types. Should I make that more explicit?

Comment: @DK Adding the line `impl<X: Sized> CanBeAdded for X where f64: Add<X> {}` doesn't help -- what should the `imp` look like? https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=59b0932a780fdcaf21848de9d310621a&version=nightly&backtrace=0

Comment: @yong Ah, I see now.  I was wrong.  The problem is that the compiler is not implemented such that it can use the information in the trait's where clause to infer `f64: Add<X>` in the function.  You can have the constraint in place, but you can't use it to force a constraint on a different type.  The simplest workaround I know of would be to implement a `fn add_to_f64(self, f64)` to the `CanBeAdded` trait directly, and not to try and use `+` itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite unlikely that a random type `X` is such that `f64: Add<X>`.

Given that `f64` is a built-in, the only module which can define implementations of `Add` for `f64` is the one where `Add` is defined. We can check the [listed implementations here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html):

- `impl Add<f64> for f64`
- `impl<'a> Add<&'a f64> for f64`

And that's all.

---

Still, if that is all that you want, you can define the trait differently.

First, we define a new marker trait. It's pretty uninteresting by itself as it has absolutely no method:

```
trait ReverseAdd<T> { type Output; }
```

Then, we add a blanket implementation, to automatically implement the trait for any type that implements `Add`, but with the relationship reversed:

```
impl<T, U> ReverseAdd<T> for U where T: Add<U> {
    type Output = <T as Add<U>>::Output;
}
```

And finally, we use it as our bound:

```
fn add2<X: ReverseAdd<f64>>(x: X) {
}
```